# Microcontroller external interrupts

Tags: sensor

i am working on project in PIC18F452 and i have some difficulties that how to connect 8 sensors to external interrupts **INT0 INT1 INT2**. Any suggestion

Comment: Do you want to connect 8 buttons to 3 interrupt pins or something else. Please elaborate what kind of sensor you mean.

Comment: object detection sensor (IR sensor)

Comment: We'd like to help, but we have no idea what you're trying to do.  Provide a link to the datasheet for your sensors, and describe in detail what you want to happen in your system.  Otherwise as close as I can get is to put an open drain output on each sensor, wire-or them all together and tie them to an interrupt, making sure your polarity is correct.

Comment: My first thought is - pick a newer chip where there are more of the pins available for interrupt-on-change. This one is obsolescent.   There are four more pins (RB4-7 ) that offer IOC on this one that give you a total of seven inputs. Are you looking for any one of the inputs to change from them all being an off state? Or detecting changes on any one regardless of the state of the others?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 256 different possible combinations on 8 sensors, you will have to use the RB[4:7] change of state interrupt capability in addition to the INT[0:2] lines (which are muxed port pins RB[0:2] anyway).

It makes writing the ISR a bit more complicated (note there isn't any sort of vector table, you have to interrogate the respective interrupt flags to put the puzzle together).

If you only have the 3 INT lines available then you will have to build the equivalent  interrupt on change using an external device such as a port expander (MCP23017 for example) that has INT on Change capability.

If you can't do that, then you are left with a priority based encoder such as a 74HC148 which is probably not going to be all that useful in your application.

Comment: if i use RB[4:7] then how i known which one is active because they all have only one interrupt.

Comment: When you get the ISR trigger, the first thing you want to do is read the RB port to save the context (this is a very old PIC processor, newer ones have an internal register that has bit-wise flags).  Then if you have an RBIF set, you compare it to the previous state to find out which ones have changed.  This is not optimal, but you should also look at what your minimum pulse width is on the sensor output, to see if it even makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using interrupts, consider polling the inputs with a periodic interrupt such as 1kHz or 10kHz.

Mechanical object detection is probably not all that time-critical and interrupts can cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: what its mean (periodic interrupt such as 1kHz or 10kHz).

Comment: You can set up an interrupt based on one of the available timers to read the pins at some fixed rate.  It reduces the complexity of checking for the various INTn and IOC interrupt flag states, with the downside being that if a sensor state changes faster than the polling rate you will miss that event.  There is a balance between how fast the sensor inputs change, the speed of the ISR and the speed of post-processing the information (such as sending the results out of a serial port).  If the rest of the process can't keep up with the rate of input data change, the system will fail.